# Where is redis installed on MacOS?

Tags: macos, redis

I have installed redis on my macOS by homebrew
I used `brew install redis`
I can use redis fine but I'm trying to find the dump.rdb file which is supposed to be under the redis installation directory. So I'm trying to find where redis is installed on my mac

I tried looking under /usr/local and did a search for dump.rdb under that

Comment: Within `/usr/local/Cellar/` I reckon...

Answer (score 8):

You can always use the `config get dir` command to get the directory where the RDB file located, and use the `config get dbfilename` to get the name of the RDB file.

Comment: These being redis commands, e.g.
`redis-cli config get dir dbfilename`

Answer (score 3):

The file should be located at

"/usr/local/var/db/redis/dump.rdb"

Answer (score 1):

This command `redis-cli config get dir` by @for_stack gives you the location where dump.rdb file directory location

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % redis-cli config get dir
1) "dir"
2) "/opt/homebrew/var/db/redis"
```

The following command `redis-cli config get dbfilename` gives the name of db filename where dump is stored

```
MacBook-Pro db % redis-cli config get dbfilename
1) "dbfilename"
2) "dump.rdb"
```

You can find the data dump file under directory like this:

```
MacBook-Pro db % cd /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis
MacBook-Pro redis % pwd
/opt/homebrew/var/db/redis
MacBook-Pro redis % ls
dump.rdb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find `redis.conf` and do some stuff inside,

```
$ cd /opt/homebrew/Cellar/redis/7.0.9
$ cat homebrew.redis.service
```

Then you will see inside where is `redis.conf`, mine is `/opt/homebrew/etc/redis.conf`

Answer (score -1):

You can check in /usr/local/Cellar/redis/5.0.9.